# Can I route PWR signals under RFIC?

Tags: power, rf, emc

I am designing an RF amplifier (< 13 GHz) and want to use a board with two layers. However, the RFIC footprint (16-VFQFN Exposed Pad) has RFIN on the left, VDD on top, RFOUT on the right, and VGG on the bottom side, see the schematic symbol.[image]

My feeding network will be above the VDD pin. All N/C pins are connected to the GND. The package has an exposed pad also connected to GND. Both layers will be filled with GND.

Considering the outlined case, **can I route the VGG signal on the bottom layer under the RFIC?**

Comment: What is the part number of the RFIC, and does the manufacturer provide a recommended layout?

Comment: @ChesterGillon, the manufacturer provides recommended layout. However, it is simplified to a version where the Vdd and Vgg are connected to pins, and no further feeding network is employed on the PCB. There is a link to part: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc441lp3.pdf (the picture in the post above is a simplified schematic symbol, as Vgg1 = Vgg2, if I understood the datasheet correctly).